# JS variable equal to html data attribute

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm trying to create a variable in my Javascript that uses the value assigned on data-start-time.

Here is my html:

```
        <li data-pile="1" id="kQKhpVWBjoQ" data-start-time="20" class="md-trigger md-setperspective">
        </li>
```

Here is my JS:

```
function playVideo(videoId, cb) {
    if(videoId) {
        myModal.find('.md-video').append($videoDiv);
        myModal.addClass('md-show');
        setTimeout(function () {
            console.log('#### id', videoId);
            var startTime = videoId.getAttribute('data-start-time');
            player.loadVideoById({'videoId': videoId, 'startSeconds': startTime});
            player.videoEnded = function () {
                cb && cb();
            };

            player.waitForChanges();
        }, 1000);
    }
}
```

If I create variable startTime and hardcode some value in my js the player works. However I 
can seem to figure out what is wrong with line:

```
var startTime = videoId.getAttribute('data-start-time');
```

All I need to do is get the value assigned in html inside data-start-time="..." for each 
"li" using the ids that vary according to the specific "li"

Comment: What is the `videoId` argument? If it's a string containing the id of the element then `videoId.getAttribute()` is an error. Try `$("#"+videoId).attr('data-start-time')`.

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
var startTime = $('#'+videoId).prop('data-start-time');
```

Assuming what the function in receiving in `videoId` is a element ID then you need to get that element by the ID. Just naming the ID will not do it. You can also use plain javascript like this:

```
document.getElementById(videoId).getAttribute('data-start-time');
```

Comment: @irm, glad I could help. Just updated my answer explaining more.